# Gnuplot key: sample and title positions

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to adjust the relative vertical position of the sample in a key
and its title? Running these commands

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output 'foo.pdf'
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]
plot sin(x)
```

produces a plot with a key that looks like this:

[image: Gnuplot key]

I'd like the sample in the key to be a bit lower relative to the title in the key (or the title in the key a bit higher relative to the sample in the key).

**EDIT:** There seem to be other issues with alignment, not just in the key.  This is the whole graphic produced by the commands above, using the latest Gnuplot installed by homebrew on OSX 10.10.5 (Gnuplot 5.2.2, cairo 1.14.12). The same thing is evident on OSX 10.11.6. At least some of the labels on the xaxis seem to be shifted a bit to the right of the tic, and labels on the yaxis seem to be shifted down.

[image]

Comment: I have encountered similar alignment issues with the `pdfcairo` (and also `pngcairo`) terminals. Other terminals, for example the libgd-based `png`,  do not exhibit this behavior. I am using gnuplot 5.2.1 on OS X 10.12 with cairo 1.14.10 and pango 1.40.13, installed from MacPorts.

Answer (score 2):

`help set key` provides you with all necessary details. In your case, probably

```
set key left
```

would already help. But there is also the option to tell `gnuplot` precisely where you want the key to be placed, using

```
# This places a key at coordinates x = 6.5 and y = 0.8 in the coordinate system:
set key at 6.5,0.8
```

Another way, rather than playing around with key positions, is also to adjust the range in a way that comfortable space is left for the key, in your case

```
plot [-10:+10][-1.1:1.2] sin(x)
```

might help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to move the whole key: I want to move the sample in the key relative to the title in the key. I've adjusted my question to try to make that more clear.

Comment: In my case, the sample and the text are perfectly aligned, no need to change. I get your point but I don't believe there is a way.

Comment: Pls also post your OS.